# 16.04 dont load on Asus n552vw

Tags: 16.04, asus, live-cd

Live-cd 16.04 don't load on my new Asus n552vw (boot hangs with no message). On the same machine Mint 17.3 works fine.

Comment: Maybe check cd for defects, check ISO against checksum and, eventually, burn CD again and do a CD-write check afterwards.

Comment: Why don't try a liveUSB. You got USB 3.0 which is like 10+ times faster than a cd.

Comment: the use of a live USB gave me the same result: 16.04 doesn't start. The USB copy is OK, loads on my old ACER without problems. At present on the new ASUS I work with mint 17.3 but I am an old ubuntu user and I would prefer to run 16.04.

Comment: Try another 16.04 iso image file. Check which one you already have (intel x86 or amd64) and try the other one too. Usually x86 image should work on all intel and amd cpus, amd64 should work only on 64-bit cpus.

Comment: No hope the intel x86 iso doesn't boot. I resume here my attempts so far:
my laptop i an ASUS n552vw-fy136t - intel® core™ i7-6700hq (2.6 ghz) - 16 gb ddr4 3200 mhz - nvidia® geforce® gtx 960m - 1 tb 7200 rpm

Tested:
16.04 amd64 version stops during boot after 15 s - I tested both  from a CD and a USB - both devices work properly on my old ACER Travel Mate.
16.04 x86 doesn't start.

With little effort I managed to load linux mint cinnamon 17.3  which  works fine.

I hope to be able to  install ubuntu 16.04 which is my preferred system.

Comment: Have you tried booting in rescue-mode (low-resolution mode)? My (wild) guess would be some 'hate' between Unity and the graphic card. After all, it boots for 15 sec and , probably, can't properly load the desktop environment (Unity). Cinnamon is based on Gnome 3, therefore is simpler and liter. nVidia is INFAMOUS for their linux driver support. I'm pretty sure that any other Ubuntu flavor (xubuntu, lubuntu, ubu-gnome, even kubuntu) is booting just fine.

Comment: I don’t know how to select the boot mode you propose for the installation CD. I can confirm the problem is note related with Unity, xubuntu 16.04 install CD doesn't load at the same stage of ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yup, it seems like a 16.04 problem. Could you try a 15.04 or 15.10? Maybe install an older version and do a full upgrade from that.

Comment: Following http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316462&highlight=ASUS I was able to run the installation CD. I set in the grub menu "nomodeset" and the installation didnot require any manual intervention. I have now dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 under uefi.

Comment: Publish your last comment as answer, so we can close yet another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Following ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316462&highlight=ASUS I was able to run the installation CD. I set in the grub menu "nomodeset" and the installation didnot require any manual intervention. I have now dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 under uefi. – Franco Jul 7 at 9:46